# Components not loading into page upon path switch (Vue.js quasar framework)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

When switching paths in Vue (using the quasar framework) the path switches but the components don't load into the page. Then, when I click refresh, the components load. Is there a way to write code that will refresh the page so the components load in?

```
<template>
    <div>
      <q-btn
        size="40px"
        round
        color="teal"
        label="F"
        to="/"
      />
    </div>

  </q-page>
</template>
```

When I click the button, I would like it to go to the / page (below) and load the maps and coordinates components in, but it doesn't do that.

```
<template>
   <coordinates />
   <maps />
</template>

<script>

export default {
    components: {
    'coordinates' : require('components/coordinates.vue').default,
    'maps' : require('components/maps.vue').default
  },
```

ROUTER CONFIGURATION:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '/', component: () => import('pages/PageUsers.vue') },
      { path: '/auth', component: () => import('pages/PageAuth.vue') },
      { path: '/buttons', component: () => import('pages/PageButtons.vue') }
    ]
  }  
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Daniel Schwartz you can reload page with this  =>   this.$router.go(0);

Comment: How is the router configured?

Comment: I answered my question down below, but if you can think of a better way I'd love to hear it. I've edited my question to include the router.

Comment: You have a redundunt '</q-page>' , not sure if that creates a problem

Answer (score 1):

After I set the children pages name it work as expected.

Your code:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/', name:'Layout',
    component: () => import('layouts/MyLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { path: '/', name:'Home', component: () => import('pages/PageUsers.vue') },
      { path: '/auth', name:'Auth', component: () => import('pages/PageAuth.vue') },
      { path: '/buttons', name:'Button', component: () => import('pages/PageButtons.vue') }
    ]
  }  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the problem in a way that is a bit hacky, but I use local storage to refresh the page.

```
load() {
  if( window.localStorage )
  {
    if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
    {
      localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
      window.location.reload();
    }  
    else
      localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
  }
}
```